# Mule Anypoint set inbound properties on a message

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, devkit

I have written a custom Anypoint connector (using devkit), and want it to set Inbound properties, much like the Mule HTTP connector does. `MuleMessage` however, does not seem to have facility to do this. 
How does one mimic this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Inbound properties are immutable, It can be achieved via the MuleMessage https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope)

However, unless your connector operation is a Message Source I wouldn't add inbound properties and instead use outbound properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
MuleMessage message = eventContext.getMessage();
            message.setProperty("key","value",PropertyScope.INBOUND);
```

You can refer the API :-https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html#setProperty

https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.3.0/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/PropertyScope.html